# how to to create new variable based on first entry of another variable

Tags: r, conditional-statements, transform

I have created `df`

```
  gvkey  year 
1  1004  1965    
2  1004  1966       
3  1004  1967      
4  1005  1950        
5  1005  1951      
...
```

`gvkey` = company id

My dataframe contains more than 1,200 unique `gvkeys` with different starting values for `year`.

I want to create a column in `df` called `ipo_date` which equals the first entry in the `year` column for a particular `gvkey`.

```
  gvkey  year  ipo_date
1  1004  1965    1965
2  1004  1966    1965
3  1004  1967    1965
4  1005  1950    1950
5  1005  1951    1950
...
```

Afterwards I want to delete all duplicate rows for `ipo_date` and delete the column `year`

```
  gvkey  ipo_date
1  1004   1965
2  1005   1950
...
```

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the first row of every `gvkey`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  group_by(gvkey) %>%  slice(1L) %>%  rename_at(2, ~"ipo_date")

#  gvkey ipo_date
#  <int>    <int>
#1  1004     1965
#2  1005     1950
```

---

Using the same logic in `data.table` and base R, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[1L], gvkey]
```

and

```
aggregate(year~gvkey, df, head, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
df = as.data.table(df)
df = df[order(gvkey,year)]
df[,`:=`(ipo_date=min(year)),by=c("gvkey")][,`:=`(year=NULL)]
df = unique(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(gvkey) %>% 
  mutate(ipo_date = min(year)) %>% 
  select(-year) %>% 
  distinct()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   gvkey [2]
  gvkey ipo_date
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1  1004     1965
2  1005     1950
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line solution:

```
library(plyr)
df <- data.frame(gvkey = c(1004, 1004, 1004, 1005, 1005),
                 year = c(1965, 1966, 1967, 1950, 1951))

df_agg <- ddply(df, c('gvkey'), summarise, ipo_date = min(year))
> df_agg
  gvkey ipo_date
1  1004     1965
2  1005     1950
```